# dimension reduction for heat equation (from 2D to 1D)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I have two metal objects of different thickness and conductivity:

1) thicker, but poorly conductive. It's properties: $k_1, H$

2) thin and much better conductive. It's properties: $k_2, h$

Addition conditions: $k_1<<k_2$ , $H>>h$

We write the heat conduction equations for both zones:
$${\frac  {\partial u}{\partial t}}=k_1{\frac  {\partial ^{2}u}{\partial x^{2}}}+k_1{\frac  {\partial ^{2}u}{\partial y^{2}}}, 0\leq x\leq L, 0\leq y\leq H,\tag{*}\label{eq01}$$
$${\frac  {\partial u}{\partial t}}=k_2{\frac  {\partial ^{2}u}{\partial x^{2}}}+k_2{\frac  {\partial ^{2}u}{\partial y^{2}}}, 0\leq x\leq L, -h\leq y\leq 0.\tag{**}\label{eq02}$$
Initial conditions $u(x,y,t=0) = u_0$
And following conditions on different boundaries:
$$\left.\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right|_{x=0,y,t} = A=const, -h \leq y \leq 0 $$
$$\left.\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right|_{x=0,y,t} = 0, 0 \leq y \leq H $$

$$\left.\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right|_{x=L,y,t} = 0, -h \leq y \leq H $$
$$\left.\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right|_{x,y=-h,t} =\left.\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right|_{x,y=H,t} =  0, 0 \leq x \leq L $$

$$\left.u\right|_{x,y=-0,t} = \left.u\right|_{x,y=+0,t}, 0 \leq x \leq L $$

$$\left.k_2\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right|_{x,y=-0,t} =\left.k_1\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right|_{x,y=+0,t} =  0, 0 \leq x \leq L $$

In several books I find reduction of dimensions for this task, but I don't understand assumptions and  to reduce dimensions of this system (how to get 1D equations from 2D equations):

$${\frac  {\partial u}{\partial t}}=k_1{\frac  {\partial ^{2}u}{\partial y^{2}}}, 0\leq x\leq L, 0\leq y\leq H, \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$
$${\frac  {\partial u}{\partial t}}=k_2{\frac  {\partial ^{2}u}{\partial x^{2}}} 0\leq x\leq L, -h\leq y\leq 0. \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

In several books I have come across methods for reducing the dimension of such a task, but I do not understand the assumptions and arguments that were made in the process of reduction. With some assumptions, I can’t agree at all.
For example one of them:

> Due to the equality of the boundary values of $u$ in both regions
>   at $y = 0$, the derivatives $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ in these regions are of the
>   same order, and therefore the flow $k\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ in the $x$ direction in the thick zone is negligible. At the same time, the heat flows in the $y$ direction coincide at $y = 0$, which can only be the case if the change
>   of $u$ in the y direction in the thick zone occurs faster than in the
>   thin. This implies $$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} >>\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

I would be glad if somebody helps me to understand in detail how to get the \eqref{eq1}, \eqref{eq2} equations from \eqref{eq01}, \eqref{eq02} equations and proof of neglection of \eqref{eq3}.

Comment: Why don't you tell us the assumptions and arguments that were made that you don't understand?

Comment: @Mattos, I edited my post and I wrote the assumption that I don't understand